# Bridge connection between Hololens, Android and Haptic Vest to send events?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, hololens

I have an issue connecting my Unity application on Hololens to a (haptic vest) Bluetooth. The problem is there is no SDK for Hololens to connect to the Haptic vest.
**- I want to maintain a connection between my HoloLens unity app and the haptic vest but cannot figure out how.

- There is an Android SDK for the Vest but I am confused about how to use it with my application. For example, I connect my Hololens to Android, and then I send events from my unity application to android to play a specific pattern because the android Bluetooth pairs with it only.
- I read about sockets TCP or UDP connection but I have no idea how this can be achieved. I am not an advanced-level programmer but just a rookie.**

Please help me regarding this issue, been stuck now for a month...

Answer (score 0):

Does the haptic vest only provide Android SDK? It is easier if there is an C# SDK.

However, it is possible If you want to have an Android device to host the bridge between HoloLens and the vest.

You may simply add a TCP/UDP Client on HoloLens. For the Android project, basically there are 2 things to do. Adding a TCP/UDP Server and implementing the haptic vest SDK. There are plenty of steps to build the system and the configuration steps for players may take long. The player needs to open Android app to pair the vest, then start TCP/UDP server. Then the player open HoloLens App, find the TCP/UDP server in the local network (maybe manually input IP address). The game starts when the connection is established.

Comment: I want to connect hololens with bhaptic vest and send some instructions (vibrate specific patterns on events). Haptic vest just have bluetooth connection which is not supported by hololens yet. And also vest has C#, Unity, Javascript, Python SDK support available. Any solutions you can suggest ? Thanks :)

Comment: If you are not familiar with Android SDK, simply use C# SDK and Unity to create 2 projects. One is targeting HoloLens 2 and is the TCP/UDP client I have mentioned. The other one is target to your android device. Unity supports targeting to multiple platforms, hence you only need to focus on one single SDK>

Comment: "Haptic vest just have bluetooth connection which is not supported by hololens yet." -> Do you mean you cannot pair vest with HoloLens? Are you using HoloLens Gen1 or Gen2?

Comment: It pairs, but does not works on HoloLens Gen2 because there is currently no support for it

Answer (score 0):

Apar from HID and Audio devices, HoloLens 2 supports the following Bluetooth APIs:

- GATT
  [Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server) and [Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client)
- [RFCOMM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm)

If your vest doesn't support accessing via the above APIs, you may need to refer to the previous answer to set up the connection.  If you have further questions on HoloLens Bluetooth, you may submit a support ticket via http://aka.ms/hololenssupport